# Intersection of images of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider two matrices: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$. I know that there exist $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$, both non-zero, such that $A x = B y \ne 0$. Does it imply that at least one column of $A$ belongs to the image of $B$? Thanks!

Comment: No. Try $A = I_2$ and $B = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Letting $n<m$ and $p=m-n$, let $A$ have $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ for columns and let $B$ have $e_{n+1},\cdots,e_m$ for the columns.